# orientdb server.bat start error: Unrecognized option: -d64

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

```
Unrecognized option: -d64
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

That's what I get when start server.bat
I installed fresh JDK 10.0.1 but it does not help.

```
@echo off
set CURRENT_DIR=%cd%

if exist "%JAVA_HOME:"=%\bin\java.exe" goto setJavaHome
set JAVA=java
goto okJava

:setJavaHome
set JAVA="%JAVA_HOME:"=%\bin\java"

:okJava
if not "%ORIENTDB_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
set ORIENTDB_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%
if exist "%ORIENTDB_HOME%\bin\server.bat" goto okHome
cd ..
set ORIENTDB_HOME=%cd%
cd %CURRENT_DIR%

:gotHome
if exist "%ORIENTDB_HOME%\bin\server.bat" goto okHome
echo The ORIENTDB_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
goto end

:okHome
rem Get remaining unshifted command line arguments and save them in the
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=

:setArgs
if ""%1""=="""" goto doneSetArgs
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%CMD_LINE_ARGS% %1
shift
goto setArgs

:doneSetArgs


if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="AMD64" goto 64BIT
set JAVA_MAX_DIRECT=-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2g
goto END
:64BIT
set JAVA_MAX_DIRECT=-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512g

:END

if NOT exist "%CONFIG_FILE%" set CONFIG_FILE=%ORIENTDB_HOME%/config/orientdb-server-config.xml

set LOG_FILE=%ORIENTDB_HOME%/config/orientdb-server-log.properties
set WWW_PATH=%ORIENTDB_HOME%/www
set ORIENTDB_SETTINGS=-Dprofiler.enabled=true
set JAVA_OPTS_SCRIPT= -Djna.nosys=true %JAVA_MAX_DIRECT% -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Drhino.opt.level=9

rem TO DEBUG ORIENTDB SERVER RUN IT WITH THESE OPTIONS:
rem -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
rem AND ATTACH TO THE CURRENT HOST, PORT 1044

rem ORIENTDB MAXIMUM HEAP. USE SYNTAX -Xmx<memory>, WHERE <memory> HAS THE TOTAL MEMORY AND SIZE UNIT. EXAMPLE: -Xmx512m
set MAXHEAP=-Xmx2G -Xms2G
rem ORIENTDB MAXIMUM DISKCACHE IN MB, EXAMPLE: "-Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=8192" FOR 8GB of DISKCACHE
set MAXDISKCACHE=

call %JAVA% -server -d64 %JAVA_OPTS% %MAXHEAP% %JAVA_OPTS_SCRIPT% %ORIENTDB_SETTINGS% %MAXDISKCACHE% -Djava.util.logging.manager=com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager$ShutdownLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file="%LOG_FILE%" -Dorientdb.config.file="%CONFIG_FILE%" -Dorientdb.www.path="%WWW_PATH%" -Dorientdb.build.number="2.2.x@rf340442755a31eabc91b87cb3ef99eda5cee6ebd; 2018-04-12 13:33:53+0000" -cp "%ORIENTDB_HOME%\lib\*;%ORIENTDB_HOME%\plugins\*" %CMD_LINE_ARGS% com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain

:end
```

That's what I have in server.bat

Comment: Please post what you have in `server.bat` so that we can better understand your problem.

Comment: Hi Yaroslav Palaguta, which version of orientdb are you using ?

Comment: set XX:MaxDirectMemorySize from 512g is too low, you need few GB at least.

Comment: there is a label for 64bit which is mine but anyway I tried (set XX:MaxDirectMemorySize = 512g) it and no result(
orientdb-community-importers-2.2.34 (my version)
readme says that I need only Oracle JDK
I'll try to connect with their support mb they will help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try older version. orientdb-community-2.2.19 worked for me.
You can find older versions on https://orientdb.com/download-previous/